# Google Apps Script HTML Service dynamically populate based on user selections

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want an HTML form where the user selects the name of the person record they wish to amend.  After the user selects a name, the details of that person need to be retrieved from a spreadsheet and used to pre-fill various fields on the form to allow the user to edit them.

How do I either:

a) update the values on the form with those from the database after the user has selected a person from a list (currently a  so that the selected name can also be updated - after the rest of the form has been populated)

or

b) show a form with just a  for person name (I can do this bit).  When the user clicks "Submit" take this data, look up the user in the spreadsheet and pass the relevant details to a new form so that the user may edit those details.

In the background, I plan to delete all the rows relating to the original selection and insert the rows based on the edited form data.

I can draw the forms and populate the various fields, but what I'm struggling with is updating the form after a selection is made in a field, or passing the values to a second form so the update can be made there.

I haven't included any code as I have nothing close to working.  I have a gs file and an html template file and know how to call one from the other.  I've tried various things but failed every time :(

Answer (score 0):

Use a DOM event listener on your input fields to call a specific Apps Script function which reads your datasource, and returns an object wrapping the needed data to a success / failure handler in the HTML file's javascript. That in-page success / failure handler would manipulate the DOM elements as necessary to display your next questions (or appropriate help messages asking for proper input, etc.)

Very relevant:

1. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener

Comment: Thanks @tehhowch, but I can't get it to work.  If I add `onchange="google.script.run.editPerson()"` the 'editPerson()` function is called, but the context of the form is not passed, so no update to the form can happen.  If I change it to `onchange="google.script.run.editPerson(this.parentNode)"` the `editPerson(form)` function does not get called.  Can you give me/refer me to an example of how it works?  I am successfully using success/failure handlers to get data from a form into a spreadsheet, but the specific example of updating an already rendered HTML form is my challenge.

Comment: @kxm start by just making a static value update (e.g. always set the value of their "Occupation" to be "painter"), entirely within the HTML file. Once you have that, the task becomes "give my static value update function the actual values". Also once you have a static value update, you are guaranteed to have code you can edit into your question so you can receive targeted help.

Comment: I've tried that - setting the value of a field to 1 in the function called onchange.  It's not working because if I use `this.parentNode` when I call the function, the function doesn't get called.  If I take this.parentNode out of the function call, then the function is called, but has no context of the form.  So I'm stuck.

Comment: Thanks @tehhowch I have the function `function editPerson(form){
  
  Logger.log("editPerson"); 
  form.getElementById('baseRate').value=1;
}` but it's not even getting called by `onchange="google.script.run.editPerson(this.parentNode)"`

Comment: @kxm You should reference functions in the HTML file as normal handlers. This will help you debug them, and avoid ridiculously long element specifiers, since when you are calling the async methods you **need** to include `withFailureHandler( )` and `withSuccessHandler( )` if you want to bring data back to the HTML page. Please review the 1st link, and also all of the example files (both .gs and .html) that it gives.